# filter datagridview with multiple keywords using dataview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

i'm using datagridview binding to datatable to show my records and i have records like this ( just example ) 
    **Name**       **Country**    **City**

```
JAck     Country1   City1
Name2    Country1   City2
JACK     Country2   City1
```

i have textbox for search i wan't to use this textbox to search in this datagridview with multiple keywords 
i wan't for example get all record for Country1 and have name jack 
i put a string in textbox like this 
[  JACK country1  ] 
i create this method to create dynamic rowfilter query based on any columns

```
 string query = "";
        Boolean firsttime = true;
        bool firstkeyword = true;
        foreach (string se in txt_ar_recherche.Text.Trim().Split(' '))
        {
            string search = (Convert.ToString(" like '%") + se) + "%'";
            if(!firstkeyword) query += " and ";

            query += "(";
            bool firstcolumn = true;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grid.Columns)
            {
                if (col.Visible)
                {
                    if (firsttime)
                    {
                        query += "Convert(" + col.Name + ",'System.String')" + search;
                        firsttime = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query += " or " + "Convert(" + col.Name + ",'System.String')" + search;
                    }
                }
                firstcolumn = false;
            }
            firstkeyword = false;
            query += ")";

        }
        (grid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = query;
```

but it's not working i don't know how to solve this problem to search with mutilple keywords in datagridview 
i wan't to create ths same textbox search that datatable javascript using , this is a demo https://datatables.net/

Comment: How generated query looks like? And what does not work? Crashing application? filtering incorrectly on some columns or something?

Comment: Did some test and if you look at you query.. you will find one irrelevant 'or' which may cause problem

Comment: But without or query loke like this ( name like '%JACK%' or country like '%JACK%' or city like '%JACK%' ) and ( name like '%country1%' or country like '%country1%' or city like '%country1%' ) it's not working

Comment: I get false resultat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this full sample:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        DataTable dataTable;
        DataView dataView;
        TextBox textBoxSearch;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            Width = 800;
            dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            textBoxSearch = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = 200 };
            textBoxSearch.TextChanged += TextBoxSearch_TextChanged;

            dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Country");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("City");

            dataTable.Rows.Add("JAck", "Country1", "City1");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("Name2", "Country1", "City2");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("JACK", "Country2", "City1");

            dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            dataGridView.DataSource = dataView;
        }

        private void TextBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var words = textBoxSearch.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (!words.Any())
            {
                dataGridView.DataSource = dataView;
                return;
            }

            var dv = dataView;

            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                var values = dataTable.Columns
                    .OfType<DataColumn>()
                    .Select(c => "Convert([" + c.ColumnName + "], System.String)")
                    .Select(c => c + " like '%" + word + "%'");

                var filter = string.Join(" or ", values);
                dv = new DataView(dv.ToTable());
                dv.RowFilter = filter;
                dataGridView.DataSource = dv;
            }
        }
    }
}
```